# PowerShell: how to archive a log file based on a specific name and date

Tags: powershell, archive, naming, logfile

I have to achieve some log files which are older than one month, and the naming convention is: filename_year_date (i.e: Logfile.log_2022_12). I've hardcoded the filename for 1 month to see if it works,  but I want to name automatically the archives with the specific files (December log files in an archive called `Logfile.log_2022_12`, January,  `Logfile.log_2023_01` and so on.

After that, the archived log file should be moved to another folder (Archive) and the log files should be deleted -  this part is done.

I have question/issue with the archive creation based on months. I don't know how to take all the files from a specific month and put them into an archive and name that archive with the name of the month. I've understood that it should be possible using switch statement or if/else if statements

```
$SourceFolder = 'D:\Temp\'
$refDate      = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Date  # take this from midnight

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceFolder -File  -Depth 0 -Exclude "*.zip" | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } |
    Group-Object DirectoryName | ForEach-Object {
        # construct the target folder path for the zip file using the Name of each group
       #$zip = Join-Path -Path $_.Name -ChildPath {
        if ($_.Name -match '^(?<filename>.*)_(?<year>\d{4})_(?<month>\d{2})\..*$') 
        {
            $filename = 'Logfile.Log'
            $year = 'year'
            $month = 'month'
    
            # Convert the year and month to a DateTime object
            $fileDate = Get-Date -Year $year -Month $month -Day 1
    
            # Check if the file is older than one month
            if ($fileDate -le $refDate) {
                # Archive the file to a zip file named 'filename_year_month.zip'
                $archiveName = Join-Path $_.Name -ChildPath $SourceFolder "$filename`_$year`_$month.zip"
                Compress-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath $archiveName
            }
        
        #}
     } 
        # archive all files in the group
        $zip = Join-Path -Path $_.Name -ChildPath "$filename`_$year`_$month.zip"
        Compress-Archive -Path $_.Group.FullName -DestinationPath $zip -Update
       
        # move archive from main folder to the Archive folder
        Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Temp\*.zip" | Move-Item -Destination "D:\Temp\Archive\"
        # here is where you can delete the original files after zipping
        #$_.Group | Remove-Item -WhatIf
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question, or are you trying to share a solution? If the latter, please describe your task in the question post, and create an _answer_ post with the code. If the former, please clarify what you're having difficulty with.

Comment: I have question/issue with the archive creation based on months. I don't know how to take all the files from a specific month and put them into an archive and name that archive with the name of the month. I've understood that it should be possible using switch statement or if/else if statements

Comment: @mklement0 I've added the part from above on the text of my problem.